# Android perimision "user's private information", "your personal information" , "read sensitive log data"

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, logging, sensitive-data

Well I found this texts on many applications, that is when I install some app the require the
android.permission.READ_LOGS permission, they show some text like "permission for reading read sensitive log data..." the thing I do not understood is what this sensitive log data means ?

Does it means that it can read my passwords ?
What is the data in this logs ?
I googled but I couldn't find anything , if you have some useful links it will be welcomed :-)

Thanks

Comment: log print which you need to print

Answer (score 1):

"Logs" in this case primarily refers to LogCat, to which any application can log whatever it wishes.

Comment: if just access logs that can be seen from logcat, why someone need to see the output from logcat ? why application such as TaskKiller need to read the logcat ?

Comment: @Luk: You would have to ask their authors why they want that permission.